# How to get access of process running on one terminal from other terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, terminal

I want to know the procedure so that i can access or get control from terminal over the process running on some other terminal in Linux .

- Both terminals belong to same system .

Comment: define "some other terminal" is this same computer? Server?

Comment: Like JosephH said, this depends on what you mean by "get control".

Comment: There is no such thing as taking control of some process already running. The most similar thing is using `screen` as described by abhi_ksd.

Comment: Given @onionjake's answer, this is a great question.

Answer (score 18):

Pehaps you want something like `reptyr`? (https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)

You simply type `reptyr PID` to 'gain control' of another process (like vim or whatnot).

Edit:

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen) has more information on using screen or tools like reptyr.

Comment: +1 I just tried this and it awesome! I needed to install it on debian (`sudo apt-get install reptyr`), but I was able to "re-parent" or take control of a process that was already running. Better than screen since the process doesn't need to be started using any special way (I had started it on my desktop and then took control of it via an SSH terminal from another system).

Answer (score 3):

Use the *screen* utility to start any process from terminal, so that you can access the same process from any other terminal either locally or remotely. For instance:

#### From first terminal

1. Start a screen using `screen -dR test` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will get shell within in screen.
2. Run you program here

#### From second terminal

1. Get in to existing screen using `screen -x test`

Now you should be able to see process running on first terminal,
and will have the full control over that process.

You can investigate more on screen utility…
its a very useful tool for any system administrator.

Hope the above tip will help you.

Comment: So if you haven't started the process using screen then you basically can't take control over it and bring it to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking SSH? If soo...

- **SSH** into the host that has the process running:

  ssh user@host

  Then to **view** processes running on the host type:

  ps aux | less

Gain Control? Not exactly sure what that means but ill list some simple commands.

- **View processes by "userName"**

  ps -u userName
- **Look up Process**

  pgrep firefox
- **Kill a process**

  *example:*

  pidof firefox

  *output: (your number will be different.)*

  2786

  *Now the kill:*

  kill 2786

**Advanced**

- shows running processes as a tree.

  pstree
- Might be interested in looking into [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/)

  atop

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread. But in the event you want à duplicate of à linux tty you can use conspy
http://linux.die.net/man/1/conspy
It is small ans easy to compile if its not already on your distribution